# How to generate points with distance between them above some thershold?

Tags: matlab

I need to generate(in matlab) **L** points in **d**-dimensional space which has to satisfies the condition that distance between any two points in the set **D** (defined below) is above some given threshold **r**.

The set **D ={ L** Union **Combination of L}**.
The other various combination of L are generated as its average. For example, the combination of point 1,5,6 is generated as (point_1 + point_5 + point_6)/3, similarly the combination 1,2,5,6 is generated as (point_1 + point_2 + point_5 + point_6)/4.

In general, the set **D** will have $\sum_{i=1}^{L} L C_{i}$ points.

Comment: This sounds more like a maths question, not a Matlab question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth looking for help in matlab code to implement this

Comment: Do you know what the algorithm is?  We can help you translate the algorithm into Matlab code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth nope :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a code that (I think) do what you explain, tell me what you think.

```
nL=6;
d=2;
r=0.1;
L=rand(d,nL); %%% generate nL random d-dimentional points

Lfinal=[];
for nn=1:nL %% for all passible size of subset of (1:nL)
  sets=nchoosek(1:nL,nn); %% all sub-set of 1:nL of size nn
  Ls=reshape(L(:,sets'),d,nn,[]); %% the corresponding Ls
  newL=squeeze(sum(Ls,2))/nn; %% their sums
  Lfinal=[Lfinal newL]; %% concatante to the final set of Ls.
end

L=Lfinal;
dists=pdist2(L',L'); %%% compute the distances between each point
dists(dists==0)=inf; %%% fill the diagonal with infinity to not use the distance between a point and it self
L=L*r/min(dists(:)); %%% multiply the points by "r/min(dists(:))" to make sure all points are at leat at distance r

L
```

Comment: Code is running perfectly fine. However, I need the points average e.g: for combination 1,2,3 the new point is (P1+p2+p3)/3 and not the sum P1+P2+P3. Now this newly generated average point should be at-least "r" distance from all of the points. In your code, the distance "r" is satisfied between the points and their sum. But i need between the points and the average. I guess im clear in conveying my requirement

Comment: Is it possible to limit the maximum distance between any two points?